# Minimax implementation not working with recursion and C++

Tags: c++, minimax

I basically have a game board, and the player can not move to the same spot more than once, or you lose.  The player can move by -1, +1, -16, or +16 only.  I want to use minimax to solve this problem, and receive the inputs used by minimax so I can see how it was done.

Here is how I am currently doing it

```
#pragma optimize("", off)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define hitcount 4

#define POINT 1
#define MINE 2
#define END 3

//4 targets: hit all 1's
//player/mine is 2
//game ender is 3
int Board[] = {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};

static const int choices[] = {
    -1, 1, -16, 16
};

struct mb {
    int end;
    int score;
    int* moveset;
};

mb solve(int Position, int *Board, int BoardSize, int *MoveSet = NULL, int Offset = 0, int Choice = 0, int Score = 0, bool tree = true) {
    if( tree ) { //tree
        int *BoardCopy = new int[BoardSize];        

        for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(choices); i++ ) {
            MoveSet = new int[256];
            for( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
                MoveSet[i] = 0xFF;

            memcpy(BoardCopy, Board, BoardSize);
            mb m = solve(Position, BoardCopy, BoardSize, MoveSet, Offset, i, Score, false);

            if( m.moveset != NULL ) {               
                if( m.end == 1 && m.score == hitcount ) {
                    delete[] BoardCopy;
                    return m;
                }               

            }

            delete[] MoveSet; //this is apparently causing problems??
        }

        delete[] BoardCopy;

    }
    else { //branch
        mb m = {0, 0, MoveSet};

        Position += choices[Choice];
        m.moveset[Offset] = choices[Choice];
        if( Position < 0 || Position >= BoardSize || Board[Position] == MINE || (Board[Position] == END && Score != hitcount) ) {
            m.moveset = NULL;
            return m;
        }
        else if( Board[Position] == POINT ) {
            m.score++;
        }
        else if( Board[Position] == END ) {
            m.end = 1;
            return m;
        }

        Board[Position] = MINE; 

        return solve(Position, Board, BoardSize, m.moveset, Offset + 1, Choice + 1, m.score);

    }

    mb m = {0, 0, NULL};
    return m;
}


int main() {

    int Position = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(Board); i++ ) {
        if( Board[i] == MINE ) Position = i;
    }

    mb m = solve(Position, Board, sizeof(Board));
    if( m.end == 1 && m.moveset != NULL && m.score == hitcount ) {
        printf("SUCCESS!\n");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

However, it doesn't work.  I cannot figure out why.  The algorithm looks like it should work, and I the problem looks to be memory cleanup related.  My VC++ studio breakpoints at _CrtIsValidHeapPtr after calling solve several times

Answer (score 0):

I cannot attest to the correctness of the algorithm. But, there are coding errors that will lead to undefined behavior that you should address.

The primary issue is that you are confusing the size of the array with the number of elements in the array. In your `main()`, you should use `sizeof(Board)/sizeof(*Board)` to determine the number of array elements for `Board`, otherwise you will read outside the array boundary of `Board`. Then, you pass `sizeof(Board)` as the `BoardSize` to `solve`, but again, this is not the right value to use when you are checking to see if `Position` is within bounds. Your outer `for` loop also computes the number of array elements for `choices` incorrectly.

As a secondary issue, you are overshadowing the `i` loop variable name with another variable named `i` in the inner `for` loop in `solve()`. Just to avoid confusion, it should probably be renamed.

So, with these in mind, I would change in `main()`:

```
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(Board)/sizeof(*Board); i++ ) {
        if( Board[i] == MINE ) Position = i;
    }

    mb m = solve(Position, Board, sizeof(Board)/sizeof(*Board));
```

Then, I would change in `solve()`:

```
        for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(choices)/sizeof(*choices); i++ ) {
            MoveSet = new int[256];
            for( int j = 0; j < 256; j++ )
                MoveSet[j] = 0xFF;

            memcpy(BoardCopy, Board, BoardSize*sizeof(int));
```

Also, you can avoid the `new/delete` business in your code fairly easily by using `std::vector<int>` for `BoardCopy` and `MoveSet`. For example:

```
        std::vector<int> BoardCopy(BoardSize);

        //...
            std::copy(Board, Board+BoardSize, BoardCopy.begin());
```

To pass in an `int *` parameter as you have in your code, you would pass in `&BoardCopy[0]`, but you should consider modifying your code to take an `std::vector<int> &`.  When you do this, you can remove all calls to `delete BoardCopy`.